# Chef role and environment default_attributes not accessible

Tags: chef-infra

Say I have the following chef role:

```
name "test"
description "role for test"
run_list %w(recipe[cookbook_name])
default_attributes(
  :cookbook_name => {
    :a => 1
  }
)
```

And the corresponding environment:

```
name "test environment"
description "environment for test"
default_attributes(
  :cookbook_name => {
    :b => 2
  }
)
```

And then in my cookbook's attributes I have something like:

```
parent = default[:cookbook_name]
parent[:c] = 3
```

The [attribute documentation](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes#Attributes-AttributeAccessorMethods) would have me believe that these would be available in the recipe context from `node[:cookbook_name][:a]` or `node[:cookbook_name][:b]`. However, when I try to access those in my actual cookbook, I get `nil`. What's going on? Am I misunderstanding the role of these attributes? I think that it's worth noting that even if I set defaults for these attributes in the attributes file, I get the same result, leading me to believe I'm accessing the attributes incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed how things should work.  Inside the "cookbook_name" recipe you should be able to access the `:cookbook_name` hash with two elements `:a` and `:b`.

Have you set the run list and environment on the node to include the role and environment you have listed?  Running `knife node show` should show this.

Comment: Yes, but it turns out the environment had failed to upload. Thanks for the good answer!